# CSS3 transform, want to keep the background image non-rotated

Tags: html, css

url is http://teothemes.com/wp/

you can check the two arrows of the slider and the triangles...I used transform: rotate(45deg), everything's great but the background image is rotated as well, if you zoom on that area you'll see some lines near the arrows, I need it to be just like the original background

I tried to add the background-image with :before and using transform: rotate(-45deg) to revert it back, but the bg image doesn't show up..it doesn't work

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Each of the properties you set are applied to the whole element. If you want different parts of it to be styled differently, then you need to use multiple styles.

If you just want to rotate the arrow image inside the element, the use the child selector, nd put the image there inside some img tags,

`div img{...}`

That way only the image will be effected, while the background image of the div housing the img will be unrelated.

If you don't get what I mean I'll clean up my answer when i'm not on my phone...